# Can't change CollectionView frame with CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to build a simple side menu using CollectionView. The problem is that I can't get it to work because changing frame using CGRect doesn't seem to do anything and the menu won't appear. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
let blackView = UIView()
var collectionView: UICollectionView {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}

func showMenu() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))



    window.addSubview(blackView)
    window.addSubview(collectionView)

    //This line doesn't work
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: window.frame.height)

    //This works fine
    blackView.frame = window.frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the collection view here:

```
window.addSubview(collectionView)
```

and the collectionView here

```
//This line doesn't work
collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: window.frame.height)
```

are different objects. You add the first collectionView to the window, and then you change the frame of the second one. The misunderstanding comes from this code:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}
```

This creates a dynamic variable, so that whenever you access `collectionView`, a new `UICollectionView` is created. It's actually equivalent to a function call. It's like

```
func makeCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}
```

and then later doing

```
window.addSubview(makeCollectionView())

//This line doesn't work
makeCollectionView().frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: window.frame.height)
```

---

What you should do instead is define the variable at the beginning, and initialize it later. For example like this:

```
let blackView = UIView()
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

func showMenu() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

    // Create collectionView
    if collectionView == nil {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    window.addSubview(blackView)
    window.addSubview(collectionView)

    //This line works finally
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: window.frame.height)

    //This works fine
    blackView.frame = window.frame
```

(depending on your code setup, you may have to create the collectionView at another place, maybe in `viewDidLoad` or something like that (I'm not sure))

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation it really helped me to understand, now its working as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

You define the wrong lazy var as the following:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView {
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
return cv
}
```

In this situation,  the following is the correct format which means its READONLY. you cannot change after return.

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView {
get{
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
return cv}
}
```

So if you want to change frame, you should change before return like this:

```
 var collectionView: UICollectionView {
get{
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
cv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300) // just an example.
return cv}
}
```

What you Really want should be like this and define it as a computed property, then you can change frame at anywhere:

```
 var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}()
```

So, basically you just miss a "=" and "()".  Hope you know the reason now.